# Failed to import demo content of premium theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am trying to import demo content of premium theme but it got stuck every time and give error in console (admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found))

Answer (score 0):

without more information it´s hard to say what´s going wrong.
admi-ajax.php is a core file first step is to check if it´s in your installation.

The file should be in /wp-admin/admin.ajax.php on your server. 
File rights should be set to 664.

Second step to isolate the problem is to disable all unnecessary plugins. 
Maybe a poor coded Plugin causes a javascript conflict.

Put this in your /wp-config.php file.

```
 define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

it will will cause the backend javascript files to load separated.
Maybe you will get more information which script is causing the error.

Some cheap hosters block access to this file. 
Contact your Hoster and make sure they do not block the access for security reasons.

Hope this helps.